# customize a checkbox

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I was thinking if there's a way to apply a style like [this](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html) onto a swt checkbox.
I looked for custom components, but didn't found anything.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:
[Create a custom button with SWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779727/create-a-custom-button-with-swt)

as a starting point. Within the `PaintListener` you can paint the button in the way you want it to look.

Here is a small example i just tried:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class ImageButton extends Canvas {
    private boolean checked = false;
    private final ImageButton button = this;

    public ImageButton(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        this.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                if(checked)
                {
                    e.gc.drawImage(Icons.ON, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.gc.drawImage(Icons.OFF, 0, 0);
                }
                button.setSize(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE, HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
                checked = !checked;
                redraw();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

where `Icons.ON` and `Icons.OFF` are the two images and WIDTH_OF_IMAGE and HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE are the width and height of the image you use.

Comment: Worked pretty well..I'll keeping looking for a way to make it 'bindable' with JFace now :D

Answer (score 2):

OPAL widgets library has that kind of buttons.

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/SwitchButton