# How to create my custom SWT control selectable?

Tags: java, swt

I can make control extending `Composite` or `Canvas`.

How to make it selectable? I.e. how to make it behave like `Button`? `Button` is disabled for extend. I see a lot of unportable code inside it.

So how to make Button-like control of myself?

Should I process mouse and keyboard events myself or there is some premade functionality to utilize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle the events yourself. I'll give you a couple of hints and references here:

1. First of all, make sure you read this: [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm)
2. Have a look at [SquareButton](https://github.com/jrobichaux/SquareButton). It's a custom `Button` widget and should contain all the code you need.
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779727/create-a-custom-button-with-swt) is a very related SO question.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is for drawing from "inside". So, you have to create your own UI input. As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526841/715269).