# paintComponent removing text value of button

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am setting background image for `JButton` or say `JTableHeader`. When I do `paintComponent` on the same, it's removing text value set for that component.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
JButton btn = new JButton(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Dimension size = this.getSize();
        g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\User\\Downloads\\MainMenu.jpg"), 0, 0, size.width, size.height, this);
    }
};
btn.setText("TEST WITH ME");
btn.setOpaque(true);
```

[image]

Comment: 1) In any overridden paint method, always call the `super` method first. This paints the background, borders etc. 2) `g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\User\\..` Don't load resources within a paint method. A paint method has to finish quickly! Load the image at application startup and store it as an attribute of the class. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: .. `btn.setText("TEST WITH ME");` 5) The text can be passed in the button constructor.  6) No need to SHOUT at the user. Better to use `"Test With Me"` or `"Test with me"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom JButton in java with an image base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235991/how-to-create-a-custom-jbutton-in-java-with-an-image-base)

Comment: You've basically broken the paint chain requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have not specified that much correct what I really wanted. But I figured out answer for that.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Dimension size = this.getSize();
    g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\User\\Downloads\\MainMenu.jpg"), 0, 0, size.width, size.height, this);
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth("String Value To Set")) / 2;
    int y = ( (getHeight() - fm.getHeight() ) / 2) + fm.getAscent() ;
    g.drawString(String Value To Set, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am setting background image for JButton

The is no need to do custom painting. You just add an Icon to the button and the button will paint the image.

If you want text on top of the image then you just use the properties of the button:

```
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(...);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(...);
```