# How to completely remove a button's background instead of just hiding it

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to create [this game](http://hwwmath.looiwenli.com/l-game)
in Java for my school A-level course. I'm currently trying to use an individual button for each of the squares and cannot in any way remove the buttons's background. I've tried `setBackground(false)` which hides the background, but it is still there so still clickable, which you can imagine completely screws up the board.

Ultimately what I'm asking is how to make a button from a picture the same size as the picture, without any extra backgrounds at all, not just hidden.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Any help/suggestions would really be appreciated, I'm desperate!

Comment: You said "I've tried setBackground(false) which hides the background".  Let's see the method you created that uses that code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BEfVGQMk forgive my probably awfully messy code, just want to get it all working before finishing it off

Comment: Anyone got anymore ideas?

Comment: Please? Really desperate. Lol

Answer (score 0):

There was a question on here for creating custom buttons with java:
[Creating a custom button in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158/creating-a-custom-button-in-java)

The answer to this question might solve your problem.